# I have a problem with a list in Python. list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove words from one list that appear in another. Then I have to copy the ones that are not repeated in a third list. When I make a comparison I have a problem with the list index

The language is python, last version.

```
listOne = ['Hello','Every','One','Here']                       
listTwo = ['Every','Here','Hi','Nice']
listThree = []

for i in range(len(listOne)):
    for j in range(len(listTwo)):
       if listOne[i] == listTwo[j]: # <-- error here
            listOne.remove(listOne[i])

 #Here is the problem
 if listOne[i] == listTwo[j]]: 
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to know why this happens.

Comment: Because you're removing items from listOne, so it gets shorter.

Comment: instead of removing items create list with items which you want to keep. It is popular method in Python.

Comment: I agree with the above, also won't listOne -once emptied from repeated elements- become listThree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list expressions to fill in list3, and a for loop and the `in` statement for the first requirement:

```py
listOne = ['Hello','Every','One','Here']                       
listTwo = ['Every','Here','Hi','Nice']
listThree = [word for word in listOne if not(word in listTwo)]

for word in [word for word in listOne if word in listTwo]:
    listOne.remove(word)
```

Comment: Where is index i defined in your code? You should add some explanation  in your answer at least

Comment: You do not need the index from what I see, you can just loop over the elements of your list. Unless I am missing a requirement here?

Comment: There was an undefined index i in your answer which you have now edited. By the way I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after posting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
listThree = [i for i in listOne if i not in listTwo]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to compare lists and remove duplicates

```
>>> listOne = ['Hello','Hello','Every','One','Here']
>>> listTwo = ['Every','Here','Hi','Nice']
>>> listThree = list( set(listOne) - set(listTwo) )
>>> listThree
['Hello', 'One']
```